# Having a problem running python script from import error of modules that i have installed on my computer

Tags: python, csv, python-itertools, matplotlib-basemap, tabulate

i have ran pip install tabulate (other Modules too) however when running script it says i am missing such modules

[import error of the various modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqRu4.png)
as you can see it says that I have an issue even when i have tabulate installed.

[evidence that i have tabulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRoiQ.png)

Comment: You may have installed it for a different Python `--version`.

Answer (score -2):

at first step check your python version with :"python --version" and upgrade pip and install your module and check "pip list" to see if its installed .
check you have activated your env
If none of the above solutions work, you can try reinstalling the module using the --user flag